# Can I use whereas at the start of a sentence

Tags: sentence-starts

Can I use *whereas* at the start of a sentence?

Comment: If you are drafting a legal document, chances are you will begin many sentences with *Whereas*. It depends on the domain, too.

Comment: First link in a google search for the word whereas: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/linking-words-and-expressions/whereas. Example sentence on the search page without clicking: "Whereas most PCs...".

Answer (score 3):

You can, indeed:

> **whereas**
>
> conjunction
>
> You use *whereas* to introduce a comment which contrasts with what is said in the main clause.
>
> - Pensions are linked to inflation, **whereas** they should be linked to the cost of living.
> - **Whereas** the population of working age increased by 1 million between 1981 and 1986, today it is barely growing.

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/whereas)

As previously noted, sentences starting with *whereas* are often found in legal documents.